# Pointer to a global variable

Tags: c#, winforms, unsafe-pointers

So, I had a code like this (detail):

```
namespace itssafe
{
    public unsafe partial class testing : Form
    {
        unsafe private static int original = 10;
        unsafe private int tmp;

        unsafe setter() // I'll use this several time
        {
            tmp = original;
        }

        unsafe private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setter();
        }

        unsafe private void timers_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int* counter;   // working
            counter = &tmp; // not working, but I need this
        }
    }
}
```

And I had a global variable, called "tmp" and I need to create a pointer what point to it. But I can't, because I get "**CS0212 You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer**" error. But the variable is global so I can't create in this method, because I need to use elsewhere too. What can I do?

I know I'm using to many unnecessary "unsafe", but i'm so desperate.

Comment: There are no global variables in C#. This is just a static field in a class.

Comment: You almost certainly do not need that; I've been working in C# for decades and never needed pointers.  Why do you believe that you need a pointer?

Comment: Have you tried putting this in a [`fixed { }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement) block like the error suggests?

Comment: Stop programming from a mindset of desperation. You will not write good solutions. **Programming in the unsafe subset is one of the hardest things to do correctly in C# and you need to have a thorough, accurate and deep knowledge of the memory model and its implementation details to do so**. Proceed like an engineer: study the system, understand its characteristics, understand the parts at your disposal, and build a robust, well-engineered solution that meets your user's requirements.

Comment: You ask "what can I do?" but we have no idea whatsoever of what you're *trying* to do, so it is impossible to tell you how to do it.  This is what we call an "XY" problem. You have a real problem. You have a completely wrong idea about how to solve it. Now you are asking a question about the wrong idea.  Don't do that. Ask a question that explains the real problem that you have, rather than the problem you are creating for yourself by using pointers incorrectly.

Comment: @Enigmativity: It's not even a static field. `tmp` is an instance field.

Comment: I see no reason for using pointers in the code you have provided. Just use `tmp` and don't try to use pointers to handle `int` as a reference type when it isn't.

Comment: @EricLippert - Sorry, I thought we were looking at `original`, not `tmp`.